# Counting Objects in Google Cloud Storage in Python Apache Beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, dataflow

I am looking to make a dataflow job with the apache beam python SDK that simply counts the number of objects in a google cloud storage bucket. However I have been unable to find any good examples of how to achieve this (most of my searches come up with word counts which is not what I'm looking to do). Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: By number of objects do you mean the number of files in the bucket? Or number of records in the files? What part of the wordcount examples doesn't work for you?

Comment: This is not a job for Dataflow. First you would need to implement normal Python code to list objects in S3 to generate an in-memory on on disk object list. Because of the next page iteration for GCS, parallelization is difficult to achieve. Then just count the objects (lines).  To actually use Dataflow you would create your pipleline with this list to do a simple reducer.